How do I stop videos stuttering when running with nordvpn
The issue is that when the nordvpn is running videos do not play smoothly.

See if you have in extensions manager an extension for
gNordVPN-local` which shows at the top bar the connection and has options for other vpn settings. If it does not show the green for update, therefore there are no updates, disable it.
That fixed the problem.
Another solution is to
while true; do sudo killall -9 nordvpnd ; sleep .1; done

That is needed as the service tries to reconnect, as it should
that means you cannot have the internet connected with the vpn and watch unstuttered videos at the same time.
Perhaps there is a manual way of updating, but for me, that was the best fix, do without something buggy.
https://github.com/Isopolito/gNordVPN-Local
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/how-to-update-gnome-extensions
I use
https://github.com/TwiN/show-my-ip
which shows my vpn IP, a secure icon for that, and does not cause problems.
NordVPN Version 3.18.2
Version: 42.9-0ubuntu2.1

noting that this extension is a third party developer, not NordVpn.

I put a bug report in https://github.com/Isopolito/gNordVPN-Local/issues/96
